# Running Chrome on Ubuntu Server? How to solve "xdg-settings: not found"? (Using Chromium without desktop session?)

Tags: ubuntu

Preface: We would like to create website screenshots using our server directly and stop using an external service. The Chromium browser has an option to generate a PNG graphic from a website. Thus, we want to use it.

We installed Chromium on our server:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Then we tried to run the browser and got this error:

```
chromium-browser --no-sandbox
/usr/bin/chromium-browser: 12: xdg-settings: not found
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

Version of Chromium-Browser:

```
chromium-browser --version
/usr/bin/chromium-browser: 12: xdg-settings: not found
Chromium 97.0.4692.99 snap
```

Trying to find more information about ["xdg-settings"](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xdg-settings.1.html):

> xdg-settings is for use inside a desktop session only. It is not recommended to use xdg-settings as root.

How to fix the error and make Chromium run?

Note 1: When running `xdg-settings` we get `-bash: xdg-settings: command not found`. Probably because there is no desktop session on a server.

Note 2: Ubuntu version is "Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS".

Answer (score 8):

```
 sudo apt-get install xdg-utils
```

This will install `xdg-settings` for you.

With Debian-based distros a `apt-cache search commandname` is a very good approach when something is missing.

Comment: Thanks. Is it save to install "xdg-utils" on a running server (with Apache, FFMPEG and other software)?

Comment: Not any more unsafe than chrome probably.

Comment: The error message disappeared. But now there are other errors popping up finishing with "Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization" ... oh my.  Even though I started Chromium with `--disable-gpu`.

Comment: Messages: `ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:894 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 0: Internal Vulkan error (-3): Initialization of an object could not be completed for implementation-specific reasons, in ../../third_party/angle/src/libANGLE/renderer/vulkan/RendererVk.cpp, initialize:1068.
ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(783)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Internal Vulkan error (-3): Initialization of an object could not be completed for implementation-specific reasons, in ../../third_party/angle/src/libANGLE/renderer/vulkan/RendererVk.cpp, initialize:1068.`

Comment: Ah, `disable-gpu` is only for acceleration. Now the question is, can Chromium be run without graphics... so can Chromium be run on a server in general. - Found this which says no: https://superuser.com/q/449005/169199 - but maybe there is a workaround?

Comment: Can you describe what your end goal is? What do you want to use Chromium for? How do you want to use it?

Comment: You are probably looking for Headless Chrome.
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome